# Why wont this align properly? CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I make the space out properly? Theres a huge gap when the screen is resized as shown in the red circle. I would like it to align properly with the other div's instead of what it is doing now. Thanks!

[image]

```css
#howItWorks h2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.services {
  position: relative;
}
.services .service {
  padding: 30px 15px 30px;
  text-align: center !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
.services .service .service-icon {
  color: #292929;
  margin-top: 15px;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
.services .service p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 385px;
  margin: 0 auto auto;
}
.services .service h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.services .service h3:after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #dee8ed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.services .service:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #dcdcda;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #dcdcda;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #dcdcda;
  background: #0084DD;
  color: white;
}
.services .service:hover a {
  color: orange;
}
.services .service:hover .animate-icon {
  color: white;
  -webkit-animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
  -moz-animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
  -ms-animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
  -o-animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
  animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .services {
    margin-top: 35px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .services .service .service-icon {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="howItWorks">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="section-heading">How it Works</h2><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="service col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
          <div class="fa-4x service-icon icon icon-Book animate-icon"></div>
          <h3>Step one</h3>
          <p>Tell us the textbooks<br> you'd like to sell<a href="sell.html"> here.</a><br><br></p>       
        </div>
        <div class="service col-md-3  col-sm-6 col-xs-12  " >
          <div class="fa-4x service-icon icon icon-Like animate-icon"></div>
          <h3>Step two</h3>
          <p>Get an instant quote for all your textbooks.</p>
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="service col-md-3  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="fa-4x service-icon icon icon-Truck animate-icon"></div>
          <h3>Step three</h3>
          <p>Mail us your textbooks for <i>free</i> using a prepaid shipping label we send you for use with Canada Post or by courier.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="fa-4x service-icon icon icon-Dollars animate-icon"></div>
          <h3>Step four</h3>
          <p>Get paid by an Interac E-Transfer or Paypal once the textbooks are received by us.</p>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the same height to the blocks, this will work.

```
.services .service {
  height: 250px;
  ...
}
```

```css
#howItWorks h2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.services {
  position: relative;
}
.services .service {
  height: 250px;
  padding: 30px 15px 30px;
  text-align: center !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
.services .service .service-icon {
  color: #292929;
  margin-top: 15px;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
.services .service p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 385px;
  margin: 0 auto auto;
}
.services .service h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.services .service h3:after {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #dee8ed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.services .service:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #dcdcda;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #dcdcda;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #dcdcda;
  background: #0084DD;
  color: white;
}
.services .service:hover a {
  color: orange;
}
.services .service:hover .animate-icon {
  color: white;
  -webkit-animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
  -moz-animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
  -ms-animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
  -o-animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
  animation: rubberBand 1s 0.2s ease both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .services {
    margin-top: 35px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .services .service .service-icon {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="howItWorks">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="section-heading">How it Works</h2><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="service col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
          <div class="fa-4x service-icon icon icon-Book animate-icon"></div>
          <h3>Step one</h3>
          <p>Tell us the textbooks<br> you'd like to sell<a href="sell.html"> here.</a><br><br></p>       
        </div>
        <div class="service col-md-3  col-sm-6 col-xs-12  " >
          <div class="fa-4x service-icon icon icon-Like animate-icon"></div>
          <h3>Step two</h3>
          <p>Get an instant quote for all your textbooks.</p>
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="service col-md-3  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="fa-4x service-icon icon icon-Truck animate-icon"></div>
          <h3>Step three</h3>
          <p>Mail us your textbooks for <i>free</i> using a prepaid shipping label we send you for use with Canada Post or by courier.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="fa-4x service-icon icon icon-Dollars animate-icon"></div>
          <h3>Step four</h3>
          <p>Get paid by an Interac E-Transfer or Paypal once the textbooks are received by us.</p>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Give a Man a Fish, and You Feed Him for a Day. Teach a Man To Fish, and You Feed Him for a Lifetime.